# Dense sets must be open in irreducible space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

If topological space X is irreducible, then open sets must be big in the sense that every two open sets overlap. I have proven that open sets are dense in an irreducible space, which is another indication that they are big in some sense. However, I cannot seem to prove the converse. That is, do proper dense sets of an irreducible topological space have to be open? Obviously, they cannot be closed, but I cannot think of an example when then are neither closed nor open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $I\subset \mathbb{C}$ and infinite numerable subset for example $\mathbb{N}$. $\mathbb{C}-I$ is dense in $C$, but it is not open for the Zariski topology since $I$ cannot be the set of zero of a finite number of polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

For a very simple example, let $X$ be any space with more than one point with the indiscrete topology.  Then $X$ is irreducible (the only nonempty open set is $X$ itself!).  But *every* nonempty subset of $X$ is dense.